# Prepare List from Different input Arrays and Objects in Jolt

Tags: json, transform, jolt

Hi I am new to JOLT transformation and I am trying to transform some thing like below.

Main goal here is to have a list of objects without making the constant indexing in jolt.

Transformation of different objects to a common list .

Any Help is appreciate .

Data provides here is an example of what I expected.

Input :

```json
{
  "CIT": [
    {
      "name": "name_CIT_1",
      "desc": "desc_CIT_1"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_CIT_2",
      "desc": "desc_CIT_2"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_CIT_3",
      "desc": "desc_CIT_3"
    }
  ],
  "BIT": {
    "name": "name_BIT",
    "desc": "desc_BIT"
  },
  "NIT": {
    "name": "name_NIT",
    "desc": "desc_NIT"
  },
  "KIT": {
    "name": "name_KIT",
    "desc": "desc_KIT"
  }
}
```

Jolt:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {}
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CIT": {
        "*": {
          "name": "CollegeList[0].name",
          "desc": "CollegeList[0].desc"
        }
      },
      "BIT": {
        "name": "CollegeList[1].name",
        "desc": "CollegeList[1].desc"
      },
      "NIT": {
        "name": "CollegeList[2].name",
        "desc": "CollegeList[2].desc"
      },
      "KIT": {
        "name": "CollegeList[3].name",
        "desc": "CollegeList[3].desc"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
{
  "CollegeList" : [ {
    "name" : [ "name_CIT_1", "name_CIT_2", "name_CIT_3" ],
    "desc" : [ "desc_CIT_1", "desc_CIT_2", "desc_CIT_3" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "name_BIT",
    "desc" : "desc_BIT"
  }, {
    "name" : "name_NIT",
    "desc" : "desc_NIT"
  }, {
    "name" : "name_KIT",
    "desc" : "desc_KIT"
  } ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "CollegeList": [
    {
      "name": "name_CIT_1",
      "desc": "desc_CIT_1"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_CIT_2",
      "desc": "desc_CIT_2"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_CIT_3",
      "desc": "desc_CIT_3"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_BIT",
      "desc": "desc_BIT"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_NIT",
      "desc": "desc_NIT"
    },
    {
      "name": "name_KIT",
      "desc": "desc_KIT"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of shift transformations. Indeed, the desired array is obtained within the first level except for the key of the array which is `root` as default. Then only renaming of the array's key occurs within the second level such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&1"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(0,&)": "CollegeList"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for the same :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CIT": {
        "*": "CollegeList[]"
      },
      "*": "CollegeList[]"
    }
  }
]
```